# is it possible to use Winform components in WPF

Tags: wpf, winforms, migration

We have a product which is developed using Winforms - .net 2.0. Now we are thinking about migrating this application to WPF. Is is possible to use the same Winform components in WPF.

Or if it is not possible, then which is best possible ways to Migrate this application to WPF.

Comment: What's the point?  You'd just end up with the same UI and same code, just more convoluted.

Answer (score 5):

Yes.  You can use [ElementHost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.elementhost.aspx) to put WPF content into Windows Forms controls, and [WindowsFormsHost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.windowsformshost.aspx) to host your Windows Forms component directly within a WPF element.

Answer (score 1):

There's a tutorial on [Switch On The Code](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-tutorial-using-winforms-in-wpf) using the `DataGridView`.

You need to add references to `System.Windows.Forms` and `WindowsFormsIntegration` to get `WindowsFormsHost`.

You can do it in the XAML as well as the C# code:

```
<WindowsFormsHost Grid.Row="0">
  <WinForms:DataGridView x:Name="_MyDataGrid">
  </WinForms:DataGridView>
</WindowsFormsHost>
```

C#

```
 _MyHost = new WindowsFormsHost();
 _MyDataGrid = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView();

 ....

 _MyHost.Child = _MyDataGrid;
 _Container.Children.Add(_MyHost);
```

Comment: Thank you Chris. Thanks for the example also. Do you have any link to such projects/code sample.

Comment: @Harsha - I don't know of any samples. Have you tried Code Project?

Comment: Ok Fine. I didn't search there. I will . . .Thanks for the direction.